# executing SqlCommand statement and displaying result in a label

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlcommand

I am executing this stored procedure and i want to change it so instead of just returning all of the results and then handling them. I want to return and display the information in the third column from the stored procedure into a label.text on my winforms app. How can i go about doing that.

```
public IEnumerable GetGuids(int id)
{
    using (SqlCommand _command = new SqlCommand("StoredProc"))
    {
        _command.Connection = new SqlConnection(conString);
        _command.Connection.Open();
        _command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        _command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemID", id);

        return _command.ExecuteReader(); 
    }
}
```

I want to display the items that will be returned in the 3rd column from the stored procedure as follows: itemRow1/itemRow2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public IEnumerable GetGuids(int id)
{    
  List<string> items = new List<string>();        
  using (SqlCommand _command = new SqlCommand("StoredProc"))
  {
      _command.Connection = new SqlConnection(conString);
      _command.Connection.Open();
      _command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
      _command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemID", id);

      using (var reader = _command.ExecuteReader())
      {
         while (reader.Read())
         {
            items.Add(reader[2].ToString());
         }
      }        
  }
  return items;
}
```

should do it for you.  Then wherever the label is, something like

```
label.Text = String.Join(",", items.ToArray());
```

or however you want to display it

Comment: should there be () at the end of `List<string>...` also i am getting an error stating cannot convert from `object` to `string` for `items.Add(reader[2])`

Answer (score 0):

It will be something like reader.GetDecimal(columnIndex)